# ELK - Time difference calculation on Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk, elapsedtime

I need to calculate the time difference and display the same on Kibana between two events from the log mentioned below, I have a unique identifier and message to identify.

```
2019-12-20 13:00:22.493 [http-nio-8080-exec-2933] INFO  c.g.i.g.m.c.GRInternalController.getGRForPO(68) - Request Started
2019-12-20 13:00:30.882 [http-nio-8080-exec-2933] INFO  c.g.i.g.m.s.i.GoodsReceiptServiceImpl.getGRForPO(1647) - Request Completed

2019-12-20 13:01:02.570 [http-nio-8080-exec-2940] INFO  c.g.i.g.m.c.GRInternalController.getGRForPO(68) - Request Started
2019-12-20 13:01:09.930 [http-nio-8080-exec-2940] INFO  c.g.i.g.m.s.i.GoodsReceiptServiceImpl.getGRForPO(1647) - Request Completed
```

Unique identifiers of the event: **[http-nio-8080-exec-2933]**, **[http-nio-8080-exec-2940]**

Time diff of [http-nio-8080-exec-2933] : **8.389**

Time diff of [http-nio-8080-exec-2940] : **7.36**

Can someone please suggest the solution to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

we can use ruby filter on logstash to achieve this:

```
ruby {

       code => "duration = 
                (DateTime.parse(event.get('time1')).to_time.to_f*1000-DateTime.parse(event.get('time2')).to_time.to_f*1000) rescue nil; 
                event.set('timedifference', duration); "
            }
```

The time difference will be in milliseconds.